# How to calculate the monthly costs of an individual Cloud Run service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-billing

I have ~30 different microservices deployed to Google Cloud Run.
Is there a way (API/dashboard/etc) to determine the 30 day costs of each individual service? Or, even better, a way to view the costs for each container over time (cost/day)?

Attempts: Manually downloading a .csv of the 30 day `Billable container instance time` graph from the `https://console.cloud.google.com/run/detail/myregion/myservice/metrics` for each service which is impractical. It is also unclear what sampling/averaging scheme is used to generate that data so the accuracy is ambiguous.

Comment: Do you sink the billing to BigQuery? If so you should find the service Name in the data. There is also this support answer: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/how-to-get-billing-report-of-a-cloud-run-service/m-p/520733

Comment: The standard method is to export billing data to BigQuery. Also review this API: [Get cost estimates for your Google Cloud workloads](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/cost-estimates-using-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways for this approach :

1st Approach uses third-party costing tools like:
Harness CCM: https://developer.harness.io/docs/cloud-cost-management/use-cloud-cost-management/ccm-cost-categories/use-ccm-cost-categories/
or Apptio: https://www.apptio.com/products/cloudability/totalcost/

2nd approach is using Google cloud-native services like Billing Sink to Bigquery, the way forward to achieve this will be as follows:

Enable the BigQuery export feature > Go to the Billing page and select your billing account > Click on "Export Billing Data to BigQuery." > Follow the prompts to create a new dataset or select an existing one > Once BigQuery export is enabled, billing data will be automatically exported to the specified dataset.

Here is a sample query that shows the total cost of each Cloud Run service:

```
SELECT
  labels."run.googleapis.com/service_name" AS service_name,
  SUM(cost) AS total_cost
FROM
  `billing_project.billing_dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX` -- replace with your dataset name and table suffix
WHERE
  service.id = "Cloud Run"
GROUP BY
  service.labels."run.googleapis.com/service_name"
```

**This query groups the billing data by the Cloud Run service name, then sums the cost for each service**

You can modify the query to get more detailed information, such as the cost per day or per hour, by adding time-based filters or aggregations. For example, to see the daily cost of each Cloud Run service for the last 7 days:

```
SELECT
  labels."run.googleapis.com/service_name" AS service_name,
  DATE_TRUNC(date, DAY) AS date,
  SUM(cost) AS daily_cost
FROM
  `billing_project.billing_dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXXX_XXXXXX` -- replace with your dataset name and table suffix
WHERE
  service.id = "Cloud Run"
  AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY
  service.labels."run.googleapis.com/service_name",
  DATE_TRUNC(date, DAY)
```

**This query groups the billing data by service name and day, then sums the cost for each service and day.**

There may be some delay between when the billing data is generated and when it is exported to BigQuery, so the results may not be real-time, for more context on this you can also follow docs: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery